# Maximum value of Product of Cosines

Tags: trigonometry

Given $$ 0 \le \alpha_1,\alpha_2, \cdots \alpha_n \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$ and
$$ \cot(\alpha_1)\cot(\alpha_2)\cdots \cot(\alpha_n)=1$$ Find the Maximum Value of $$ \cos(\alpha_1)\cos(\alpha_2)\cdots \cos(\alpha_n)$$
NB: A small hint will suffice

Comment: I don't know whether this helps, but the condition on the cotangents implies that the product of the cosines equals the product of the sines. But the bigger the cosine, the smaller the sine.

Comment: I think that if your question has been answered then you should accept the answer given or ask for more information if you want.

Answer (score 12):

since 
$$\sin{a_{1}}\sin{a_{2}}\cdots\sin{a_{n}}=\cos{a_{1}}\cos{a_{2}}\cdots\cos{a_{n}}$$

so
$$(\cos{a_{1}}\cos{a_{2}}\cdots\cos{a_{n}})^2=\dfrac{1}{2^n}\sin{2a_{1}}\sin{2a_{2}}\cdots\sin{2a_{n}}\le\dfrac{1}{2^n}$$

with equality if and only if $a_{1}=a_{2}=\cdots=a_{n}=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Nice. I suppose you mean to write, "with equality if and only if...."